# How can I get rid of extra halos from ceiling can lights?

Tags: lighting, lens-flare, real-estate

How can I get rid of the extra halo beneath the light when taking a photo?

I'm not seeing the effect with other types of light fixtures. Both reference photos are minutes apart using the same camera settings.

After doing some research it seems like it might be a dirty lens, but the example photos show more streaky light behavior and not what looks like a second exposure.

Also, I'm not sure what to call it. Is it a lens flare?

Weird Effect:

[image: image showing ceiling can lights with doubled flare below]

Normal looking exposure:

[image: Pendant light fixtures shot without the halos]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an internal reflection... if you have a filter on the lens remove it. It is common for the front element of a lens to be multicoated to reject/reflect light that might cause flare, and that can be reflected back by the filter as a second image.

If you do not have a filter, then it is light reflecting off of the sensor or another lens element. In that case there is no solution I am aware of.

If there is a single bright source in the scene you can place it dead center so that the reflected (ghost) image directly overlays the primary image and is (mostly) hidden... but that is not the case here.

Comment: OK, yes I had two filters on, a polarizer and ND filter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Matthew If that answer worked for you, consider marking it accepted (click the gray check mark under the answer's votes.